# Query MS SCOM effective configuration of servers via java

Tags: java, windows, monitoring

Short version: our Windows servers are managed by SCOM 2007.  We want to pull the effective monitoring configuration for each server into our systems management infrastructure via java.

The Export-SCOMEffectiveMonitoringConfiguration looks good but it's for 2010 and we are on 2007 R2.  I can't get a date yet for planned upgrade.  The SCOM guys are way over in a different leg of IT from us systems management guys.  All the hits I find are either 1) about monitoring java processes, webapps, WASen etc or 2) require VB or C# or 3) about subscribing to alerts which we already do via a SCOM-BEM bridge .

At a scrape I can code in VB but the team is java-based so it's a problem for ongoing support. And the code we already have for our unix and other servers is all in java.  So best case may be bending over and writing a stand-alone app in VB/C# to produce something our java can consume?
eta: j-Interop looks useful.

Does the SCOM WSDL allow us to query effective configuration of a server?

RTFM answers welcomed if you can point me at the right FM.  At the moment I am in a maze of twisty little URLs, all pointing to the wrong info.